# How can I pass flags to rustc from a build script if they contain a space?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am writing a Rust program with some C integration so I'm using a custom build script. In this script, I pass `-L <path to library>` to `rustc`, but this works only if `<path to library>` does not contain a space. 
The exact line in the `build.rs`:

```
println!(r"cargo:rustc-flags= -L {}/target/sdsl/sdsl_install/lib -l sdsl -l divsufsort -l divsufsort64 -l stdc++", current_dir);
```

If `current_dir` contains a space I get this error

```
error: Only `-l` and `-L` flags are allowed in build script of `top_tree_compression v0.1.0 (file:///home/jan/Uni/Bachelorarbeit/Programme/Top_Tree%20Compression)`: `-L /home/jan/Uni/Bachelorarbeit/Programme/Top_Tree Compression/target/sdsl/sdsl_install/lib -l sdsl -l divsufsort -l divsufsort64 -l stdc++`
```

I tried to write a `\` before the space to escape it but it gives me the same error. Then I tried to replace the space with `%20` because in the error message the space was replaced with this, but then I get a linking error because the path is not correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you cannot as of Rust 1.29. The [source code for the current master of Cargo](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/blob/a5d82949485802abb45f888d5b8b7f23927f031d/src/cargo/core/compiler/custom_build.rs#L497-L499):

> ```
> let mut flags_iter = value
>     .split(|c: char| c.is_whitespace())
>     .filter(|w| w.chars().any(|c| !c.is_whitespace()));
> ```

This naively splits the argument on any whitespace, regardless of where it occurs. This seems to be a bug or limitation of Cargo and you should look for an already-filed issue or file one yourself.

---

That being said, if you use the more fit-for-purpose `rustc-link-lib` and `rustc-link-search` parameters, spaces work fine:

```
println!(r#"cargo:rustc-link-search={}/target/sdsl/sdsl_install/lib"#, "some thing");
```

```
$ cargo run --verbose
   Compiling xx v0.1.0 (file:///private/tmp/xx)
     [...snip...]
     Running `rustc [...snip...] -L 'some thing/target/sdsl/sdsl_install/lib'`
```